# Question about polygons.

Tags: geometry, polygons

Consider a polygon $A_{0} \dots A_{n}$. Why does there exist diagonal $A_{i}A_{j}$ without intersection of polygon. It's looks obvious but why?

Comment: First of all, don't put the word "stupid" in your title. Second, your question is unclear. What do you mean by "...without intersection of other polygon"? Lastly, what have you tried yourself?

Comment: @vrugtehagel my bad , sorry

Comment: It does hold for concave polygons, if I understand the OP correctly

Comment: @vrugtehagel Thanks for the reminder. I took existence as "for all"...

Answer (score 0):

A convex polygon is a non-empty intersection of convex sets (half-planes), hence it is convex. In particular, if we consider the segment joining $A_i$ and $A_j$ with $|i-j|>1$, such segment lies inside the polygon, since it is the convex envelope of $A_i$ and $A_j$.